# ASP.NET code generator for creating pages for lookup tables

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a code generator that will create basic maintenance asp.net pages for lookup tables stored in sql server.  I can clean up the pages after they are generated and connect them to my business objects.  I just wanted the controls to be generated to create a starting point.  Do any exist?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) and see if it helps.